# Lightbox 2.51 NOT WORKING. I click on thumbnail and big image opens in NEW PAGE

Tags: html, image, lightbox

This lightbox is kicking my butt. I'm trying to use 2.51 and when I click on the thumbnails it just opens the big image on another page instead of lightbox. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I was curious if you knew where I was going wrong. I added rel="lightbox" to all the link attributes but it still doesn't work. Would appreciate your help. Here is the coding:

website url: http://www.traydius.com/html/digital_thumb_PAGE4.html

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
 <link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href=" css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
 <script type="text/javascript">
 <!--
 function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
 var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
 }
 function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
 var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
 var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
 if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
 }

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
 var p,i,x; if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
 d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
 if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
 for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
 if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
 }

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
 var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
 if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
 }
 //-->
 </script>
 <style type="text/css">
 <!--
 .style1 {
 font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif
 }
  .style4 {
 font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 20px;
 }
 .style6 {
 font-size: 20px
 }
 -->
 </style>
 </head>
```

Comment: none of your JS files are being called correctly, check your console, there are 6 errors. Where is your html file in relation with the javascript files?

Comment: add `../` right after the `src` in your `script` tags. ie. `../js/prototype.js`

Comment: I'm not really sure what your asking or telling me. I don't know what check my console means or where I do that at. I don't know where to go in dreamweaver to check for errors. I've looked but I don't see a error checker or something to tell me this line is incorrect. As far as my html files go, I basically have a folder in the root of the site with a folder labeled HTML. All of my html files are in that folder. The lightbox javascript files i downloaded are in the root in a folder labeled JS. And the images are in the root in a folder labeled IMAGES.

Comment: I added the ../ after the src tags but I'm still getting the same results

Comment: where are you javascript files in relation to your html?... same folder? a folder behind? folder ahead inside another folder...?

Comment: Well I have my main website root folder then inside there I have a folder called: images, js, css, html....etc. All of them are all seperate folders in the root folder. I was able to fix the problem by what you said. I had to study the code and i finally got what you were saying. You have to forgive me. Coding is not my thing, I'm slow when it comes to that.

Comment: So now lightbox seems to be working but the problem is all the images that are suppose to show up on lightbox for example: the close image, next, back,....etc. The spots where they go all have a "X" where they go so it not locating them. I have all of those in my images folder. Are they suppose to just sit in the root folder in order for lightbox to see them?

Comment: okay, where those images are being called you need to make sure that the path is correct. for example: your in html/index.html and you want to reference a file in the images/ folder you need to add ../images/file.png the ../ character takes you one folder back. and obviously if you need to go into a folder inside another you just add /folder name, for example: root/html/index.html

Comment: Okay, we are almost there. I got the close button to show up and the prev and next arrows show up but the problem now is that in IE9 im getting a "X" at the top of the loading box and the loading spinner at the bottom just keeps spinning. In Firefox the Loading box at the bottom just keeps spinning. I uploaded my changes so you can get a idea of what I mean. Hear is the url:   http://www.traydius.com/html/digital_thumb_PAGE4.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Wordpress, it's probably an error with another plugin or the theme's footer file conflict.

See this link: 
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/2011-gallery-images-open-in-new-window-not-lightbox?replies=23

- The lightbox may not be appearing because of a permalink issue, go to Settings >> Permalinks and reset your permalinks to 'Post Name', save changes > clear browser cache and try again
- Plugin compatibility issue: Go to Plugins tab and deactivate all plugins (including NextGEN) and re-activate NextGEN only. If that works, re-activate all other plugins one at a time until it stops working again to find the plugin conflict

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for replying on a verry old topic.
It seems that lightbox doesn't load the images if you display them by using the "[gallery link" tag in the WP post.

Answer (score -2):

Lightbox 2.51 Use Jquery only...

Erase those lines
// script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js">

// script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder">

// script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js">

// link rel="stylesheet" href=" css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />